# Play images from an array of images

Tags: android

I'm doing a simple android program where I want to play images one after another from an array of images after clicking a button of my main XML file .
But the program close unfortunately.

**Code:**

```
package com.example.play_image;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
//import android.view.View;
//import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int imageList[]={R.drawable.exam_a,R.drawable.exam_b,R.drawable.exam_c,
  R.drawable.exam_d,R.drawable.exam_e};

ImageView letter;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){     
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}    

public void play_image(){
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        letter.setBackgroundResource(imageList[0]);
    }
}
```

**XML file:**

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"    
>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="158dp"
    android:background="@drawable/exam_a"
    android:onClick="play_image" />   
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have another question:

1. I want to play image like each image will appear in the screen and stay for some period (like 10 seconds) and then appear another .how should i do that?
2. What should i do to add animation on that images?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your ImageView. like this:

```
ImageView letter = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
```

and in your play_image method i would add this:

```
public void play_image(ImageView letter){

//your code

}
```

and then when you start it just pass the imageview object to it like this

```
play_images(letter); //or any other imageview
```

Next in your play_images method i'm sure your aware that you weren't changing the image presented. You left 0 as the array item. you need to replace 0 with I or what ever Int your using in your for loop.

also your loops logic could be simplified by using the following:

```
   for(int res : imageList){
        letter.setBackgroundResource(res);
    }
```

if its still not working you could try using a drawable by replacing the letter.setBackgroundResource line. like this:

```
    letter.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(int res id));
```

Comment: should I create any ImageView named "myImageView"in my xml file?

Answer (score 0):

first declare your image view

```
letter = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.xxxxx);
```

for animation ,you have two ways:

1) use `AnimationDrawable`

```
AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = new AnimationDrawable();
    animationDrawable.addFrame(frame, duration);
```

frame is drawable so should get drawable from you id

```
Drawable frame = getResources().getDrawable(imageList[x]);
```

2) use runnable

```
int i=0;
runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            letter.setBackgroundResource(imageList[i]);
            if(i<5){
                handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
                i++;
            }
        }
    };
    handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(runnable);
```